# Morse functions are dense in $C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})$ questions.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, morse-theory

Hi here is a proof inspired from the reference below. Feel free to get very technical with your comments so that at the end I understand it well. 
I am more concerned about the questions I added below, so if you want feel free to go straight in answering the questions.

Morse function is generic in $C^{\infty}M$,where M is compact smooth manifold.

Proof:

Step 1

Given any smooth f on M we have:

By compactness $\exists$ finitely many coordinate charts $ \{V_{p}\ ,\ \phi_{p}\}$,$M\subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{N}V_{k}$ 
 with coordinates $x_{p,1},...,x_{p,m}\ $.

Define $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^{N\cdot m}\times M\ni (\lambda_{p,i},x) \mapsto  f(x)+\sum_{p}\sum_{i=1,...,m}\lambda_{p,i}x_{p,i}(x)\cdot \phi_{p}(x) \in \mathbb{R}$

$\Rightarrow d\Phi:\mathbb{R}^{N\cdot m}\times M\to T^{*}M$, $d\Phi(\lambda_{p,i},x)=df(x)+\sum_{p,i=1,...,m}\lambda_{p,i}dl_{p,i}(x)$.

Step 2

We will show that $d\Phi\pitchfork 0_{M}$ and so we can approximate f by a Morse function.

Any $x\in M$ is contained in some $V_{p_{x}}$ and so setting $\lambda_{p,i}=0 ~\forall ~p\neq p_{x}$ we get:

$df+\sum_{i=1,...,m} \lambda_{p_{x},i}dx_{i} \Rightarrow$ by varying $\lambda_{p_{x},i}$, we get

span$(x,\{df+\sum_{i=1,...,m} \lambda_{p_{x},i}dx^{i}\})=\{x\} \times T_{x}^{*}M $

$\stackrel{0_{M}~const.}{\Rightarrow} T(T_{x}^{*}M) =\{x\}\times T_{x}^{*}M+T_{x}^{*}M\times \{x\}=T_{x}(d\Phi_{x})+T_{x}(0_{M})\stackrel{P.~Tran.(*)}{\Rightarrow}$

$d\Phi_{\lambda}\pitchfork 0_{M} $ ~ a.e. $\stackrel{\lambda\to 0}{\Rightarrow}f(x)+\sum_{p,i=1,...,m}\lambda_{p,i}l_{p,i}(x)\pitchfork 0_{M}$ $ \square$

(*) By P.Trans., I mean the following lemma:

If smooth $F:M\times S\to N$ has $F\pitchfork Z\subset N$,then $f_{s}\pitchfork Z$,where $f_{s} (x)= F(x,s):M\to  N ~$ for a.e. s.

$\textbf{Questions}$: Is $\Phi$ well-defined in the intersections of charts i.e. $V_{p}\cap V_{p'}$ ?
Is the arguement "by varying... we get span" missing something? If yes,can you please tell me what?

Thank you so much

proof from http://www.math.toronto.edu/mgualt/Morse%20Theory/Notes5-8.pdf